# How to code vba to open internet explorer in new session?

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, excel, webautomation

I am struggling to get this done since months, how to code VBA to open internet explorer in new session i have an application with many logins  i need to open them simultaneously using automation , i have used

```
  set ie=new InternetExplorer
```

but it opens the ie within the old session, i want to open new session for each and every login please help me, i googled a lot for it but ended up with out any solution.
 this is my code

```
 Function GetIE() As InternetExplorer

  Dim WScript
Dim objShellWindows

 Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows
 Set WScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


 Dim ieStarted
 ieStarted = False

  Dim ieError
  ieError = False

    Dim seconds
      seconds = 0

  While (Not ieStarted) And (Not ieError) And (seconds < 30)

If (Not objShellWindows Is Nothing) Then
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim IE


    For Each objIE In objShellWindows

        If (Not objIE Is Nothing) Then

            If IsObject(objIE.Document) Then
                Set IE = objIE.Document

                If VarType(IE) = 8 Then

                    If IE.Title = EmptyTitle Then
                        If Err.Number = 0 Then
                            IE.Write LoadingMessage

                            objIE.navigate Sheet1.Login.Text
                        ieStarted = True
                        Set GetIE = objIE


                      Else

                       MsgBox ErrorMessage
                            Err.Clear
                            ieError = True

                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

        Set IE = Nothing
        Set objIE = Nothing
    Next
End If

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:1")
seconds = seconds + 1
Wend

 Set objShellWindows = Nothing
 Set objShell = Nothing



   End Function
```

with this code im able to open the browser but sadly my webpage is opening in outlook which is already opened pls help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the `-nomerge` argument will prevent session merging.

```
Shell("iexplore.exe -nomerge http://www.yoursite.com")
```

**UPDATE**

As per your comment, you need to get the IE object. You may be able to work with this:

```
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

wshShell.Run "iexplore -nomerge http://www.google.com"

Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Dim objShellWindows
Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

Dim i
Dim ieObject
For i = 0 To objShellWindows.Count - 1
    If InStr(objShellWindows.Item(i).FullName, "iexplore.exe") <> 0 Then
        Set ieObject = objShellWindows.Item(i)
        If VarType(ieObject.Document) = 8 Then
            MsgBox "Loaded " & ieObject.Document.Title
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

Set ieObject = Nothing
Set objShellWindows = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
Set wshShell = Nothing
```

Comment: this is opening a browser in a new session but i couldn't get ie object for it, please check the code i have attached. i need to have the functionality to work as "when we open New Session from file menu"

Comment: You might be able to adapt [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7595348/74757). I'll see if I can get it simplified and will update my post if I can.

Comment: thank you so much the code in the link you have given  is working perfectly except i need to have my home page blank for it to work:(

Comment: with the code you have given im getting the object of the explorer which is already opened before this exlorer

Comment: @nothingisimpossible: Unfortunately I'm not a VBA programmer and I really just hacked this together. You might have to search for your IE instance by URL, or inspect the window properties for clues about which window is yours.

Comment: Please check the updated code i was using that but my webpage is opening in Outlook which is laready openend

Comment: Pls help me with this i want it to opne only in internet explorer not in outlook

Comment: @nothingisimpossible: then you need to incorporate the check for the process name (see the line with `"iexplore.exe"` in it above).

Answer (score 5):

Using Excel 2010 - This is what I use with a command button. Replace google.com with the website you want to open in another browser.

```
Private Sub commandname_Click()

'Opens an Explorer with a web site 

Dim IE As InternetExplorer

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  IE.navigate ("http://WWW.GOOGLE.COM")

  IE.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add `Microsoft Internet Controls` in `Tools` > `References` for this to work.

Comment: Or use `Dim IE as Object` to keep using late binding.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22787353/7077298) works for me after changing:

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
```

to

```
Dim IE As Object
```

Comment: You need to add `Microsoft Internet Controls` in `Tools` > `References` for that to work.