# How can I open two web browser in a different session?

Tags: vb.net, http, proxy, client, webbrowser-control

There are 2 web browser.

I want them both to open different sessions

how to make?

vb.net code?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no further description of the problem [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184340/how-to-code-vba-to-open-internet-explorer-in-new-session).

> Apparently the -nomerge argument will prevent session merging.
>
> ```
> Shell("iexplore.exe -nomerge http://www.yoursite.com")
> ```