# MS Access Webbrowser: New Session

Tags: ms-access, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I usually start an external internet explorer with the VBA Code

```
wshShell.Run "iexplore.exe -nomerge"
```

as stated in [How to code vba to open internet explorer in new session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184340/how-to-code-vba-to-open-internet-explorer-in-new-session)

i.e. the nomerge tag to start a new session. Now I am using the Webbrowser in MS Access: How do I open a site there in a new session? I have an enterprise-internal application, that will always run on the same session in all IE-instances (including MS Access Webbrowser), if not started with File->New Session or -nomerge flag.

Is there any way to set the MS Access Webbrowser into nomerge mode? Thanks.

Comment: Please explain your question clearly. You're using the Web browser control in a forrm? And you want to have multiple instances of that form?

Comment: yes I'm using the webbrowser object that you can drag on a form in ms-access, just where you can get a button. I want to have a fully nomerged instance, because if you dont start a nomarged (i.e. "new session") instance of our website, all other internet explorers that navigate to this website will interfere with the on-form webbrowser session. I have had this problem in several large swiss enterprises with their enterprise applications, that only a new session allows independent navigating. Hop I made it clearer :)

Comment: short answer: YES to your 2nd question. All first other internet explorer instances OR first other webbrowser instances on that same website should be in another session.